# Welcher Satz ist richtig? 0-Position

Tags: word-order

Mein Lehrer hat uns etwas gesagt, aber ich bin davon nicht ganz überzeugt. Er hat uns erzählt, dass 'und' sowie 'aber, oder, sondern,...' immer auf 0-Position im Satz stehen.
Ich habe geschreiben:

> "Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, dass ich um 7:00 Uhr aufstehen muss und meine Schwester um 8:00 Uhr aufstehen muss".

Mein Lehrer hat mir empfohlen, etwas anders zu schreiben:

> "Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, dass ich um 7:00 Uhr aufstehen muss und meine Schwester muss um 8:00 aufstehen"

Was denken Sie darüber? Meiner Meinung nach ist 'meine Schwester um 8:00 Uhr aufstehen muss' auch ein Nebensatz, deshalb muss das Verb 'muss' am Ende stehen. Meinem Lehrer nach soll 'und' immer auf 0-Position stehen und danach ist das Subjekt und danach ist das Verb.

In diesem Zusammhang, welcher Satz ist richtig:

> "Damals war ich ein Student an der Universität und war meine Schwester eine Schülerin"

oder

> "... und meine Schwester war eine Schülerin"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich kann nicht recht erkennen, was diese Frage mit der Position von "und" zu tun hat.

"Und" kann (unter anderem) verwendet werden, um zwei Haupt- oder Nebensätze zu verbinden. Damit steht es außerhalb der (Teil-)Sätze, die es verbindet. Man kann das als 0-Position bezeichnen, aber besonders glücklich finde ich diese Bezeichnung nicht. Etwas anderes ist es, wenn "und" am Anfang eines Satzes steht, z.B. "Und dann ging ich nach Hause". Hier steht "und" in der Tat an der 0-Position, da "dann" die 1-Position einnimmt.

Zur konkreten Frage:

Beide Sätze sind grammatikalisch korrekt, aber sie sagen nicht dasselbe aus.

Im zweiten Satz würde ich den Teil nach "und" als Hauptsatz verstehen, da das Verb an zweiter und nicht wie in einem Nebensatz üblich an letzter Stelle steht:

(Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, dass ich um 7:00 Uhr aufstehen muss) und (meine Schwester muss um 8:00 aufstehen).

D.h. das Aufstehenmüssen der Schwester wird als Tatsache geschildert und nicht als Aussage des Vaters. Das ist stilistisch aber problematisch, da anscheinend etwas anderes ausgesagt werden soll.

Es ist zwar zulässig, Verbzweitstellung für den nachgeordneten Satz zu verwenden und das "dass" wegzulassen. Aber dann sollte diese Struktur auch konsequent befolgt werden:

> Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, ich muss um 7:00 Uhr aufstehen und meine Schwester muss um 8:00 Uhr aufstehen.

Meine Präferenz wäre eine gekürzte Version des ersten Satzes:

> Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, dass ich um 7:00 Uhr und meine Schwester um 8:00 Uhr aufstehen muss.

Zur zweiten Frage: Üblich ist "Damals war ich Student an der Universität und meine Schwester [war] Schülerin".

Comment: Das Problem ist, daß Hauptsätze auch Nebensätze sein können: *Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, ich muß um 7 Uhr aufstehen* (was den Irrsinn der Terminologie aufzeigt).

Comment: @DavidVogt Das stimmt zwar. Aber wer im selben Satz zuerst sagt "dass ich…muss" und dann "und sie muss", der redet doch sehr widersprüchlich und missverständlich, wenn er zwei Aussagen des Vaters meint.

Answer (score 1):

Die Korrektur ist nicht korrekt.

"Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, dass ich um 7h aufstehen muss und meine Schwester um 8h." hier wird im Allgemeinen kein weiteres Verb benötigt. Man kann kann es hinzufügen, doch wird der Satz dann zu:

"Mein Vater hat mir gesagt, ich muss um 7h aufstehen und meine Schwester müsse um 8h aufstehen."

Verwechsele aber nicht 'müsse' mit 'müsste'. Dies würde die Bedeutung deutlich ändern. Nun Deutsch-Hardcore: Stünde dort müsste, hätte die Schwester eine Wahl. Ich kann die Beugung leider nicht begründen - es hört sich mit 'muss' einfach falsch an.

Man kann es auch noch anders machen, dann fehlt aber etwas:
"Mein Vater sagte mir, dass ich um 7h aufstehen muss und dass meine Schwester um 8h aufstehen muss/ müsse."